# Laravel Database Foreign Key Constraints not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm a beginner in Laravel and I think I might have missed something really important.

I am trying to put Foreign Key Constraints in my database.
I have tried to migrate my work (php artisan migrate) and it goes to the database.

However, when I want to see the "connexion" between my primary key and my foreign key on mysql, nothing shows up.

When I test it by adding an article and a tag, I can add the wrong ID on the database.

Tag Table:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTagTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tag');
    }
}
```

Article Table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateArticleTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('article', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->longText('content');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('article');
    }
}
```

Article Tag Table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateArticleTagTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('article_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('tag_id');
        });

        Schema::table('article_tag', function($table){
            $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('article');
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tag');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('article_tag');
    }
}
```

[My test with the article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg4DO.png)

[My test with the tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFsL8.png)

[My test with the article_tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqACB.png)

The table article_tag should not work with ID 1 and ID 3.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe the default table engine on your MySQL is MyISAM.. use query `SHOW ENGINES` to check that. MyISAM doesn't support Foreign Key Constraints InnoDB does support Foreign Key Constraints

Comment: Confirm that the MySQL tables are using `ENGINE=InnoDB`, and that `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` is enabled. (Foreign key constraints are not enforced for ENGINE=MyISAM tables.)

Comment: Besides it's better is to add a `$table->engine = 'InnoDB'` to every `Schema::create` this way you always enforce the MySQL server to create InnoDB engine tables.

Comment: Do i have to add it to all the tables?

Comment: Thanks guys I have now another problem, but I have already find a stack overflow solved issue (SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the database configuration and set the engine value to InnoDB

config > database.php

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB',
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateArticleTagTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('article_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('tag_id');
    });


        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('article');
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tag');



/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function down()
 {
     Schema::dropIfExists('article_tag');
 }
}
```